# Kibana - reporting option is missing

Tags: kibana, elastic-stack

According to [Getting Started](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/reporting-getting-started.html) page there is an option of `Reporting` present in Dashboards.

But it is not present in any of my dashboards. Here how my top bar looks like :
[image]

What am I missing?
I am using kibana 6.3 version.

Comment: You need to install X-Pack: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/6.3/reporting-settings-kb.html

Comment: @Val it is mentioned [here](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/x-pack) that in version 6.3 it is installed already, i am still not able to find the required settings. if i add settings, kibana stops working.

Comment: please show the settings you're adding and show what error kibana gives you.

Comment: in which file do i need to add the settings? there are currently no mention of xpack in elasticsearch.yml and kibana.yml file @Val

Comment: The first line of the link I shared above states: `You can configure xpack.reporting settings in your kibana.yml`

Comment: when i add any setting in `kibana.yml`, kibana stops working. @Val

Comment: .... and show what error kibana gives you.

Comment: @Val sorry for the confusion, i meant kibana is not loadking at all. it is unable to connect to `localhost:5601`. i have made changes in `kibana.yml` and restarted kibana service

Comment: please share the ES + Kibana logs

Comment: i have also have same issue...any answers??